# Como voltar um arquivo em um campo input type file?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, arquivo

Tenho um formulário html que faço o upload de um arquivo e consigo salvar em uma pasta. O problema é que agora preciso fazer a operação inversa, e voltar o arquivo nesse mesmo campo do tipo input type file para que o usuário possa editar. Alguém pode me dar uma ajuda, ficarei grato. Já tentei salvar no value desse input e mesmo assim não vai.

Comment: Nunca vi algo do tipo. Já tentou usar algo como o `FileReader` do `Javascript`?

Comment: Você deve ter salvo o nome do arquivo em algum banco ou arquivo, para poder recuperar e colocar o nome de volta no _input_.

Comment: Já tentei dessa forma, mas mesmo assim não volta. Consigo escrever o que vem do banco na tela , mais não em um input do tipo File, apenas text.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não é possível *setar* o valor de um `input type="file"` por questões de segurança.
Do [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_fileupload_value.asp):

> **Note:** This property is read-only, because of security reasons.

Uma alternativa é colocar um link para o arquivo perto do `input` com o título "Arquivo atual", por exemplo. Caso for uma imagem, poderia exibir essa imagem e colocar o *label* do `input` como "Alterar imagem".